# Can I call the "Set" method of a struct property using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, f#, system.reflection

I define a struct:

```
public struct Settable
{
     public string SettableProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I can set the value of the struct's property in the usual way:

```
s.SettableProperty = "Abc";
```

However, when I create a method to attempt to set the property by reflection:

```
public T CreateWithValue<T>(string propName, string propValue)
{
    var retObj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);

    var _ = prop.SetMethod.Invoke(retObj, new object[] { propValue});
    return retObj;
}
```

...and call it thus:

```
var x = CreateWithValue<Settable>("SettableProperty", "Abc");
```

...I end up with `SettableProperty` initialized to its default value, `null`. (No exception is thrown.)

Note that if I define Settable as a **class** instead of a **struct**, the value is set as expected.

**Is it possible to set struct properties using reflection?**

Comment: As a side note: having a mutable struct is usually a terrible idea; if I had a vote on this, I'd **strongly** recommend using `public readonly struct Settable` with a `get`-only property that is set via the constructor.

Comment: @MarcGravell - noted. This is test code where I'll eventually end up with many structs that I want to be able to easily value-compare, which Assert.AreEqual can do with structs. I also want to make them mutable for test flexibility. Do you recommend making them classes and using a different comparison method, or does this seem like a reasonable time to use mutable structs?

Comment: that is a very subjective thing; what I *do* know is that I have helped an *awful lot* of people fighting with mutable structs - they cause a lot of confusion

Comment: Welp, it took 5 hours, but I'm running into mutable-struct-related problems. Advice taken.

Comment: but think how much you learned in the process! (glass half full, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `retObj` is `T`, a value-type, but `Invoke` takes `object`. This *boxes* the value, which creates an isolated copy on the heap (inside the box), which you then mutate. Your local copy in `retObj` isn't impacted in any way here, since it is a completely disconnected copy of the value.

Consider instead:

```cs
public T CreateWithValue<T>(string propName, string propValue)
{
    object retObj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);

    prop.SetMethod.Invoke(retObj, new object[] { typedValue });
    return (T)retObj;
}
```

This creates the box *earlier*, and unboxes it to get the modified value. It is, however, not very efficient (note: I haven't *added* any inefficiency; the inefficiency is inherent when using an `object` API with a value-type). You can remove the allocations if you're happy to get much much dirtier.